# What is the best way to estimate hosting/server costs?

Tags: linux, web-server, hosting, bandwidth, benchmark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good sites for discussing specific hosting provider/server specification scenarios](https://serverfault.com/questions/292013/good-sites-for-discussing-specific-hosting-provider-server-specification-scenari)

I'm currently developing a web app that is built on the LAMP stack. I want to know how I can estimate how much bandwidth, storage, processing, etc. it will take when I hit a certain number of users. What are some tools I can use to make these estimates?

Comment: Use a load testing tool to test whatever equipment you have then extrapolate from there.

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of Sargon and Systat to log processor usage, nic in/out traffic, memory usage, and storage. Then it is just a matter of correlating that data with your traffic and calculate pricing based on that information. Hope that helps!